# link image file path embedded HTML

Tags: images

I fail to understand  how to link image file path from upload media to embedded HTML
I want to apply proportioned  images to my embedded HTML so that pics display correctly in the article text body

this is link to site

http://freecodecampersreferencebook.tk/

I Also get a security warning I don't know how to fix...

any help apricated.

Comment: http://freecodecampersreferencebook.tk/

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you mean from the phrasing of this question. Are you trying to edit an image and crop it to a particular size? Make sure that images are always the same proportions? Please edit your question and clarify if you can.